# Failing to attach database

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I am trying to attach a .mdf file in an asp.net 3.5 project to MS SQL Server 2008, so I will be able to open the database and edit it. I have tried to go to server management studio -> connect to server instance -> right-clicked databases and pressed attach -> press add in the "attach database" section. An explorer pops up but it is not able to guide me to the file I want to attach. What can be wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio shows the drives on the server that SQL Server is installed. I assume this is not an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, have you installed SP1 for Visual Studio 2008?
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440724.aspx) about supporting SQL Server 2008 in Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio(V 10.0.1600.22).  File > Connect Object Explorer

In the Dialog box that pops up change the Server Type to SQL Server Compact Edition.  Then you will be able to choose the .mdf you want.